# Ajax always returns error even when succeeded

Tags: ajax

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: someUrl,
                type: "PUT",
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    message: "bla",
                    date: this.Date
                },
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Failed to save.");
                }
            });
```

someUrl is a method for saving in database, and it gets called and is succeeded, it add new row in my table in database.
But, I always get the alert. In 'data', there is error 500 and it says "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'date' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'MyMethod(Int32, System.String, System.DateTime)'".

Comment: Use Firefix + Firebug. Open the NET tab and look at your request and response. This is likely due to your server code and not your AJAX call.

Comment: @Diodeus But the server method is ok, it never crashes.

Comment: type: "PUT", <-- change to GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely not an error with your AJAX code, it's an error on the server side. Check logs on the server when you call someUrl.

In other words, the is AJAX call is 'succeeding', but the server is returning a 500 error.

Comment: But the server method is ok, it never crashes.

Comment: A 500 response simply means that there was some kind of error on the server side. The server will still returns an HTTP response, and has nothing to do with your JQuery code. In fact, it's possible that your database has been updated, but the server side code has some other error.  (See this page for a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650958/non-nullable-type-system-datetime-asp-net-mvc). By the way, PUT requests should be idempotent, if you are "inserting" lines into a database, you should probably be using a POST request.